# how to display excelsheet record in pandas?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, readfile

**Read whole workbook**

```
aspire = pd.ExcelFile(r"F:\sanofi\aspire\2019\Aspire Final - FF BLANK DEC2019.xlsx")
```

**Read sheet 1**

```
sheet_1 = pd.read_excel(r"F:\sanofi\aspire\2019\Aspire Final - FF BLANK DEC2019.xlsx",sheetname=0)
```

**Read sheet 2**

```
sheet_2 = pd.read_excel(r"F:\sanofi\aspire\2019\Aspire Final - FF BLANK DEC2019.xlsx",sheetname=1)
```

**Read sheet 3**

```
sheet_3 = pd.read_excel(r"F:\sanofi\aspire\2019\Aspire Final - FF BLANK DEC2019.xlsx",sheetname=2)

sheet_2.head()
```

**Error:**

```
NameError: name 'sheet_2' is not defined
```

Comment: I'm assuming each block of code above is a cell in a jupyter notebook. Make sure you're running them in order and resolving any issues as you  execute the cells. The  `pd.read_excel()` function does not have a `sheetname` argument. It should be `sheet_name`. With that change, the code runs on my machine without issue.

Comment: I realized that `sheetname` was the variable in pandas 0.20, but changed to `sheet_name` in pandas 0.21